# Activequery where clause with a join

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables, Notes and Accounts. A note can have many accounts. I am attempting to get all notes of a certain type that were created after January 1, 2015. I would also like to load the accounts at the same time using the `.joins` function of ActiveQuery.

This is what I am attempting:

`notes = Note.joins(:account).where(type: 'red').where('created_at > ?', '2015-01-01')`

This should give me an array of all `Notes` of `Type` 'red' that were created after the first of the year. The issue is that `created_at` is ambiguous. How do I specify that I want it to refer to `notes.created_at`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the table name on `where` clause:

```
Note.joins(:account).where(type: 'red').where('notes.created_at > ?', '2015-01-01')
```

Comment: Definately thought I tried that. Must have had a typo in my attempt. Thanks